# User-defined List instance

Tags: class, haskell, types

This is supposed to be really simple, but I cannot seem to get around it.

Suppose I have my own List class, declaring `head` and `tail` in its interface. `List` is supposed to be what you expect, that is a collection of homogeneous items.
Then, I want to create a `data` type implementing the `List` interface.

The following code is what I came up with, but it does not work: how would you fix it?

```
class List l where                                                             
    head :: l -> a  -- ERROR! How do I tell: given a list, return an element?                                                      
    tail :: l -> l                                                             

data ConsList a = Nil | Cons a (ConsList a)                                    

instance List (ConsList Int) where                                             
    head Nil = error "Empty List"                                              
    head (Cons h _) = h                                                        
    tail Nil = error "Empty List"                                              
    tail (Cons _ t) = t
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a meta-comment: it's somewhat common for Haskell beginners to declare classes too often. It's possible you just want to write two functions of type `head :: ConsList a -> a` and `tail :: ConsList a -> ConsList a`, not a class.

Comment: As an example for a somewhat more general "list class", consider parsec's [`Stream`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/latest/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#t:Stream)

Comment: @DanielWagner I agree with you! I'm just working my way through Okasaki's book, which explains many implementation of the same interface, and I got stuck at page 3 with this problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rather than defining `List` a type class, define it as a *constructor* class:

```
class List l where
    head :: l a -> a
    tail :: l a -> l a                                        

data ConsList a = Nil | Cons a (ConsList a)

instance List ConsList where
    head Nil = error "Empty List"
    head (Cons h _) = h
    tail Nil = error "Empty List"
    tail (Cons _ t) = t
```

Alternatively, fix the element type (note: for your type `ConsList`, this requires flexible instances):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

class List l where
    head :: l -> Int
    tail :: l -> l

data ConsList a = Nil | Cons a (ConsList a)

instance List (ConsList Int) where
    head Nil = error "Empty List"
    head (Cons h _) = h
    tail Nil = error "Empty List"
    tail (Cons _ t) = t
```

Finally, with type families you can do even more fancy stuff, but it really depends on your specific scenario if you should go that far (probably not):

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies      #-}

class List l where
    type Elt l
    head :: l -> Elt l
    tail :: l -> l

data ConsList a = Nil | Cons a (ConsList a)

instance List (ConsList Int) where
    type Elt (ConsList Int) = Int

    head Nil = error "Empty List"
    head (Cons h _) = h

    tail Nil = error "Empty List"
    tail (Cons _ t) = t
```

Comment: in your second example - you have `head::l->Int` is this a typo or intended, if latter I don't understand it, it would only work on lists of ints, or do I miss a point. Admittedly I have not met `flexible instances` yet.

Comment: @epsilon'εⳆ2'halbe It's intended. It fixes the element type for the lists abstracted over to `Int`.

Comment: but is it right that so it only works for `List Int` and for others `head` wouldn't make any sense and all the nice polymorphism would be gone??

Answer (score 7):

You can

- make it a constructor class,

  ```
  class List l where
      head :: l a -> a
      tail :: l a -> l a
  ```
- make it a multiparameter type class with functional dependencies

  ```
  class List l a | l -> a where
      head :: l -> a
      tail :: l -> l
  ```
- use a type family

  ```
  class List l where
      type Elem l
      head :: l -> Elem l
      tail :: l -> l
  ```

I consider the constructor class the best way to go about it.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to make an abstraction over lists is to abstract over the *type constructor*, i.e., over `[]`, not over `[a]` (which is syntactic sugar for `[] a`).

So your class becomes:

```
class List l where
  head :: l a -> a  -- now l is applied to the element type
  tail :: l a -> l a
```

Then your instance changes accordingly:

```
instance List ConsList where
  ...  -- code as before
```